# IntelliJ does not stop tomcat/tcServer

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

As described, the latest version of IntelliJ does not stop tomcat/tcServer.

It says it has stopped/disconnected, but the process is still running and it's available in my browser on port 8080.

In order to actually stop it I have to kill wrapper.exe and then kill all java processes.

This is becoming tedious.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing on the newest version of IntelliJ (2016.1.1). This maybe a bug, as I'm seeing it on both my Mac and Linux workstations. Since I haven't noticed it until now, it may be related to a specific configuration profile.

I'll add a ticket when I track down when exactly it occurs (it's intermittent for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using the Tomcat provided "startup" and "shutdown" scripts under the "Run Configuration -> Startup / Connection" tab. The defaults don't work always.